# Angular 7 equivalent to angularJS code for element cloning

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular7, clone

I am learning Angular. I have a project that I use for learning purposes. I am on the section where I would like to add endless item types as it does in [this example](https://codepen.io/sampow/pen/VeJVGp).

```
;(function () {
   'use strict';

   var DemoController = function($scope){
      $scope.selectData = [
         {
            'name':'Rasmus Lerdorf',
            'lang':'PHP'
         },
         {
            'name':'James Gosling & Patrick Naughton',
            'lang':'Java'
         }
      ];
      $scope.informations = [
         {
           'inputName' : '',
           'inputSelect' : '',
            'inputCheckbox' :'',
            'optionsRadios' : ''
         }
      ];

      $scope.cloneItem = function () {
         var itemToClone = { 
            'inputName': '', 
            'inputSelect': '',
            'inputCheckbox':'',
            'optionsRadios': ''
         };
         $scope.informations.push(itemToClone);
      }

      $scope.removeItem = function (itemIndex) {
         $scope.informations.splice(itemIndex, 1);
      }

      $scope.submitForm = function() {

      }
   }
   angular
      .module('app', [])
      .controller('DemoController' , DemoController);
      DemoController.$inject = ['$scope'];
})();
```

I know that this example is old. Possibly from Angular 1. I couldn't find aywhere an example for element cloning.

I would appreciate if you can help me to understand how cloning elements works in Angular7.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: As I mentioned I am new in Angular. Didn't have a clue how to clone. I can clone with jQuery but not Angular. I am trying to understand the code @Adrian Brand posted.

Comment: @Zze please see my comment below regarding the Angular element clone Google search. How new programmers suppose to learn Angular if they cannot find a useful source. So far https://angular.io/ and examples in https://stackblitz.com were helpful. I would appreciate any recommendation for learning Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is AngularJS, not Angular.

You have a data structure for your model.

```
export interface Developer {
  name: string;
  language: string;
  selected: boolean;
}
```

Then you make a component with an array of them

```
  developers: Developer[] = [{ name:'', language: '', selected: false }];

  add() {
    this.developers.push({ name:'', language: '', selected: false });
  }
```

And in the view you ngFor over the array.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let developer of developers;let i = index">
  <input [name]="'name_' + i" [(ngModel)]="developer.name" type="text">
  <select [name]="'language_' + i" [(ngModel)]="developer.language">
    <option>PHP</option>
    <option>Java</option>
    <option>Angular</option>
    <option>TypeScript</option>
  </select>
  <input [name]="'selected_' + i" [(ngModel)]="developer.selected" type="checkbox">
  <br>
</ng-container>

<button (click)="add()">Add</button>
```

Best way to learn Angular is playing on StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksgsnm?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Woaww! That website is awsome. Thanks for that. It is like jsFiddle for Angular but more advance. Apparently it is online version of Visual Studio Code. I am looking into the example code you provided. If I have any questions I will ask you. By the way, I indicated that the code I provided was Angular v1. AngularJS is Angular v1? Am I wrong? Thanks again for everything.

Comment: I reviewd the code. Everything is so clear and simple. When I searched "angular clone element push" all the results were related to AngularJS have a look here https://www.google.com/search?ei=yAuTXPSdO9TSz7sPrtKIkA0&q=angular+clone+element+push&oq=angular+clone+element+push&gs_l=psy-ab.3...143888.145213..145688...0.0..0.272.746.2-3......0....1..gws-wiz.FmfLZ_w1vTw  So strange. Even when I filter and show only results from past month, only this stackoverflow topic is found related to search. The rest of the topics are just not related. Doesn't give any idea how to clone an element.

Comment: You really made my day. Thank you again. I am so grateful to you.

Comment: I tried to upvote but I get this warning "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score... I am trying to rename the form input names. They should be like this each time they are cloned language-2 language-3, language-4 etc. I tried something like this "formControlName={{language+ i}} but couln't increase the numbers . Can you please show me how to change the name of the cloned inputs by updating the stackblitz. There is no rush. Whenever you have a free time.

Comment: Take a look at the code above, you bind the index of the ngFor to a view varbiable i and then change the name from attribute binding to property binding and calculate a string with i

Comment: Thank you so much.